# Show a list of all forms

Tags: forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list all the form IDs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/how-to-list-all-the-form-ids)

I have been searching for a way of listing all forms that are hooked to a Drupal site. I have read this post [How to list all the form IDs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/how-to-list-all-the-form-ids), saying that it is impossible.

Now impossible is a big word in my vocabulary;-) If need be I can scan every single module file for the hook_form () function. Yet I am seriously hoping there will be a less hack like solution no matter what the resource cost might be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this list?

Comment: I have a assignment at work that requires me to list all forms through the Servises REST server so they can be used as content in steps for a BPM engine. Since my boss here is not easily convinced that we should deviated from the plan...well I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up using Hook_form_alter () to add every form that was being called (and was not on my form list yet) to a form list.

Then I wrote an admin interface that enables the administrator to select what forms are still active/should be listed. Next to this I implemented a REST service for the Services module to GET the list of forms.

The fact that the hook_form_alter () has to preform a DB request to see if the form is on the list everytime a form is viewed is some what performance heavy, but since there is no help, this is the best I can think of. If anyone has interest in the code, drop me a line, ofcourse better ideas are welcome;-)